# How can we charge our clients for an API service that is build with AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, billing

My company is building an API service that will be offered on our own website.

We are considering to deploy it on AWS API Gateway + Lambda to make it scalable.

After doing some research, I'm not really sure how we can do manage our clients' subscriptions & billing.

Can anyway recommend a service that let us charge and manage clients that are using APIs that are build on AWS?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered api keys and [usage plans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html)?

Comment: thanks @Marcin - Yes I saw that, but I'm not sure how I can connect this to an actual billing system that clients that open an account on my site, pay can get the api key. Any idea if there is such a system that integrates with API Gateway that offer this integration?